# How to enable map command in vim?

Tags: perl, vim, perl-tidy

How to enable map command only when filetype is 'perl'?

something like:

```
if(&ft=='perl')
  map ,pt <ESC>:%! perltidy<CR>
endif
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the shorter way.

Add this line to your ~/.vimrc

```
au FileType perl nnoremap <buffer> _t <ESC>:%! perltidy<CR>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/perl.vim`.
2. Put this line in that file:

   ```
   nnoremap <buffer> ,pt <ESC>:%! perltidy<CR>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have below lines in my `.vimrc`. the first one sets the "tab" unit for any "perl" filetype and the second one runs `perltidy` with `_t` keyboard shortcut. THis many not get you the exact answer but surely should get you some pointers:

```
autocmd FileType perl set tabstop=4|set shiftwidth=4|set expandtab|set softtabstop=4
nnoremap <silent> _t :%!perltidy -q<Enter>
vnoremap <silent> _t :!perltidy -q<Enter>
```

I have been using these setting in my `.vimrc` for last 5+ years. The credit goes to whoever came up with these commands. I did not make above commands.